# How ajax open a link of node in custom region?

Tags: 7, navigation

Please help someone who knows how to deal with this. I'm not the first day trying to realize this. But unfortunately nothing sensible on the subject on the Internet is not found.

By default in drupal when you link (example, http://site.domain/node/7) to page content of material is loading on a full page.
I need to make so that when you click on link (example, http://site.domain/node/7) first is loading the front page and then over it ajax loading content of material (/node/7) in custom region. How it can be best implemented? I would be grateful for tips.
I create regions in theme and them work well.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much time to write the example code for you at this moment, please try to digest the steps below. Let me know if you find some points which you don't understand.

1. Duplicate a new ajax endpoint (e.g. ajax/node/%node`) for`node/%node`in`hook_menu`.
2. Alter the menu item 'node/%node' with custom page callback.
3. In the custom page callback, load front page content.
4. Load a custom JS file in the page callback.
5. In block admin, move a empty block to the desire region.
6. In the custom JS file, use [`l_ajax()`](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_links_api) to load the content `ajax/node/%node` to the target DIV.

Comment: I postponed the implementation of this function, but again came the moment when I had to return to this problem. Unfortunately I am not a developer of Drupal. I looked many videos and articles about Ajax, but was never able to solve this problem. Of all the review it seems to me that your option is what I need. I wrote a document on how I understand the algorithm you described. [https://goo.gl/wr2RfJ](https://goo.gl/wr2RfJ) document can be edited if you wish. Most of all I do not understand, paragraph 1 and 2. If you have the opportunity to see my document. I thankful for any help. Thank you.

Comment: @makbuk It is my pleasure. I will go to visit that link for providing more details. But it's nearly at midnight here. I will come back tmr.

Comment: Did you have time to look at the documents? Can you explain what you mean **Duplicate a new ajax endpoint** (paragraphs 1 and 2)?